# How to force reload page when next.js router push the same route with different query?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I'm developing a product detail page with `/proudct?id=xxx` route, when user in `/proudct?id=1` jump to `/proudct?id=2`, only state dependency `router.query.id` change, I want to force reload the whole page instead of update some state.

Comment: just use `router.push(/product?id=2)` and put `useEffect` to handle `id` changes or else try `window.location.reload()`

Comment: `window.location.reload()` will reload whole app, redux global state will lose. I just want to reload page, like jump to different route page, page component reload

Comment: Then use the first option which I suggested router.push + useEffect

Answer (score 1):

There is an upcoming but still unstable feature `unstable_skipClientCache: true` where you can skip the client's cache, see snippet below.

```js
const router = useRouter()
const { pathname, asPath, query, locale } = router

router.push(
  {
    pathname,
    query
  },
  asPath,
  {
    locale: newLocale,
    unstable_skipClientCache: true
  }
)
```

I use it for locale changes on my page as the session depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this using replace and then reload.

```
router.replace("/product?id=2").then(() => router.reload());
```

Answer (score -2):

what worked for me was something like this but it doesn't feel like a good fix.

```
router.replace({
   pathname: '/[whatever]',
   query: { param_key: param_value },
}).then(() => router.reload())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).